# implement part of a github repository

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm trying to modifyt this repository which I forked https://github.com/vinnytwice/BicycleSpeed
but without the use of the tableviews because i'm interested in display the data like speed cadence and distance inside a more graphically designed InfoSpeedoViewController.
I don't manage tableviews controller yet so I can't understand how and where to modify the project.
Can anybody help to point me in the right direction?
my version will have just two ViewControllers :
MainViewController with a ScanButton and SpeedoViewController

So far I deleted the InfoTableViewController.swift, that is just drawing the tableview. but I'm stuck in modifying MainViewController according to my needs. I don't understand the override function prepare(for segue ) part of the code. it passes data to the InfoTableViewController with the first if statement so I don't need it, but with the second if statement it starts the scan function bluetoothManager.startScan() and passes data to ScanViewcontroller via it's UINAvigationController and than to the tableView in the ScanViewController. Am I right?
If so, could I just call the scan function and pass data to my SpeedoViewController instead?

```
@IBAction func scanButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    bluetoothManager.startscan()
    performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: MainToSpeedoSegue, sender: self) 
}
```

I don't really understand the relationship with scanViewController I guess. does data end to the infoTableView anyway?
thank

Comment: I found a solution to my problem I think. in mainViewController.swift I get rid of all the ScanViewController related stuff as: weak var scanviewController:ScanViewController?,  the override func prepare(for segue:) completely and get my values from returned values of the func vualuesForPreviousMeasurement function in measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. it was to change the tableViewController for a normal ViewController having labels to display values. Change the references from the tableViewController to the ViewController, and link the returned values to the labels inside the function that was receiving the  continuously updated values.
Pretty easy once decoded the data flow.